# What are the best known bounds on the Hermite polynomials?

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

The best I could find on the net is this paper,
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0401310.pdf

Has this been improved?

Comment: What kind of bounds? pointwise? Lp norm? The polynomials themselves or the spectral coefficients related to them?

Comment: I would most importantly like to have bounds on sums like $\sum_{i=D}^\infty a^iH_i(x) H_i(y)$ where $a<1$ and $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $D$ is some positive integer. Any bound you can help me find which will help bound sums like the above will be helpful!

Comment: I'd include that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not a comprehensive answer, but [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002190459090104X) contains some pointwise bounds on Hermite polynomials. It seems that it gives a different flavour of the $L^{\infty}$ bound by splitting it to $\mathbb{R}$ bounds and "central" bounds.

Also, for what it's worth, it seems that no one who's citing the aforementioned paper has a better bound.