# Error estimate in the spectral theorem of compact operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, integral-kernel

Given a compact self-adjoint operator $K$ mapping $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow  L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ as $f \rightarrow \int K(x,y) f(y) d\mu(y)$,  let us define its eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and eigen-functions $e^i(x)$.

Let us define a sequence of "partial sum" operators $K_N(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i e^i(x)e^i(y)$. Then this sequence converges to $K(x,y)$ in the product Hilbert space under the product measure.

More explicitly then,
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \int \int |K(x,y) - \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i e^i(x)e^i(y)|^2 d\mu(x)d\mu(y) = 0.$$

> But is there any example where for some specific $K$ someone has tried estimating this error-integrand $|K(x,y) - \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i e^i(x)e^i(y)|^2 $ ? I would be hapy to find any reference along these lines..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm following [Szego's book on orthogonal polynomials](https://books.google.co.il/books?hl=en&lr=&id=RemVAwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR9&dq=szego%20orthogonal%20polynomials&ots=l4bK485fTQ&sig=S6hN5M_fZqiHhr2ny7sOcV0oSpU&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=szego%20orthogonal%20polynomials&f=false).

In chapter III he considers $f \in L^2\left((a,b),d\alpha \right)$, with $-\infty \leq a < b \leq \infty $. There exist a set of orthogonal polynomials $\{p_n \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ w.r. to the measure $d\alpha$.

We consider the kernel $K_n(t,x) := \sum\limits_{\nu=0}^{n} \bar{p_{\nu} (t)} p_{\nu} (x) $. Then one can show that $\int\limits_{a}^{b} K_n (t,x) f(t) \, d\alpha (t) = \sum\limits_{\nu = 0}^{n} \hat{f}(n)p_n (x) $, the spectral expension of order $n$.

So, if we settled that the polynomial expansion of $f$ is an integral transform, there's a detailed discussion in Szego's book, Davis "approximation theory" and many other books about its $L^2$ error.

**Edit:** If we look in [Aronszajn (1950)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1990404.pdf?_=1461643206256), we can have by Section 9 that the kernels converge in L^2 norm.

**Edit 2:** I recommend you to read the aforementioned paper, as it deals with the much broader class of reproducing kernels, and give a lot of conditions and results that are relevant to your question.

Comment: Well, I am looking to estimate things like the value of what you call $K_n (t,x)$. You think Szego's book does this?

Comment: You mean section 5.7 in Szego's book?

Comment: 5.7 deals with Hermite and Laguerre polynomials, but for more general information about it look at chapters 14-15. What kind of error norm are you interested in?

Comment: I am interested in trying to estimate the difference between the Gaussian kernel and a finite truncation of its spectral expansion which is in terms of Hermite polynomials. At least this is one special case I am immediately interested in. (...I vaguely understand that these spectral expansions are somehow special because the sequence of partial sums here converge uniformly on compact sets - this is some special property for which I don't have much intuition as of now..)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure that $K_N(t,x) \to K(t,x)$ pointwise, and not only in $w*$ topology. I'll ask about it in a different question.

Comment: That is Mercer's theorem which is giving this uniform convergence of $K_N(t,x)$ to $K(t,x)$ on compact sets. But I am hard-pressed to see which parts of Szegos' book helps compute this error term.  To be clear - if $\phi_i$ are the eigenfunctions of the kernel with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ then I am looking to estimate the value of $\vert K(x,y) -  \sum_{i=1}^D \lambda_i \phi(x) \phi(y) \vert $. I went through quite a few sections of Szego's book I can't see anything which helps with this.

Comment: (..and this is very tricky because for the Gaussian kernel the eigenfunctions are the Hermite polynomials and they are diverging exponentially in both $i$ and $x$..)

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, you want pointwise convergence of the kernel. I'm almost entirely sure that it doesn't say anything about it in this book. For some families of orthogonal polynomials (hermite, jacobi etc.) there are papers about the convergence of the expansion, but I'm not sure what about the convergence of the kernel.

Comment: Could you kindly refer to these papers where people have thought of bounding a sum of a finite number of products of Hermite polynomials?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/236977/what-are-the-best-known-bounds-on-the-hermite-polynomials

Comment: Oh! That was a separate question I had anyway asked :) What is confusing to me about this reference of yours is that they seem to claim that they have "constants" C, D, E in their theorem 1. That looks way too strong to be believable. Like in the paper I referred to in my question the pre-factors multiplying the $n^{-1/6}$ are themselves also diverging as $n!$. Could you kindly comment on this?

Comment: What is very confusing is this, $K(x,x) = 1$ (for the Gaussian kernel). So $1 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i \phi_i^2(x)$. Now $\lambda_i \sim a^{-i}$ for some $a <1$. But $\phi_i$ contains a factor of $H_i$ and that is exponentially diverging in $i$. No way are the prefactors of $\phi_i$ being subdued by the rate of fall of $\lambda_i$. How on earth is this converging to $1$!?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the presumption that the partial sums of the kernel converge to it in $L^2$ of the product is not quite right: for example, mapping $\ell^2\to \ell^2$ by $e_n\to \lambda_n\cdot e_n$ for a sequence of real numbers $\lambda_n$ going to $0$, but slowly, gives kernel $K=\sum_n \lambda_n\cdot e_n\otimes e_n$. For $\lambda_n$ going to $0$ slowly enough, certainly $\sum_n |\lambda_n|^2=+\infty$, so the kernel cannot be in $L^2$ of the product. This obstacle exists prior to talking about spaces of functions on reasonable physical spaces.

In general, asking about pointwise (much less uniform pointwise) convergence is somewhat worse, when the Hilbert spaces are concrete spaces of functions.

So maybe this is not quite an "answer to the question", but a reaction and request for clarification.

Comment: So for what kind of operators can I assume this kind of a convergence in L^2 of the partial sums? (I am assuming that its a compact self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space) If the operator is compact then the spectral theorem holds (theorem 2.5, page 20 here https://people.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/spectral-theory.pdf) . In  that case are there examples of being able to estimate the error in partial sums in the equation 2.9?

Comment: @gradstudent, are you familiar with Hilbert-Schmidt operators?

Comment: Yes. These kernels are Hilbert-Schmidt operators.

Comment: Are "reproducing kernels" the same as Hilbert-Schmidt operators?

Comment: Hilbert-Schmidt operators are a proper sub-class of compact operators, namely, exactly the class of compact operators whose naturally-plausible kernel does converge in $L^2$. "Reproducing kernels" are kernels giving the identity map on some function-space, and possessing some pointwise or uniformly locally pointwise convergence ($L^2$ convergence for the identity map could happen only on a finite-dimensional space...)

Comment: Isn't theorem 2.5 in my reference saying that the partial sums of the compact operator's spectral decomposition are converging in the L^2 norm? So you are saying that for HS-operators more is true as in their symmetric, positive-semi-definite, bounded kernels also have the same spectral decomposition and their partials sums are conveging in L^2?

Comment: Partial sums of _general_ compact operators' spectral decomposition do _not_ converge in $L^2$. That latter convergence is exactly the property of being Hilbert-Schmidt, and most compact operators (self-adjoint or not) are _not_ Hilbert-Schmidt. (Also, H-S ops need not have positive semi-definite kernels...) And, even then, the partial sums of H-S kernels admit no better estimate for convergence than would something in $\ell^2$ admit estimates for its convergence. That is, arbitrarily bad-but-convergent possibilities do occur.

Comment: Okay. I have been looking at the spectral decomposition theorem and clearly I am not understanding something. (1) Could you kindly clarify what is the convergence guarantee in the spectral theorem for compact and/or self-adjoint operators? (2) The definition of HS operators in my reference above seems to indicate that they are by definition formed as integrals of a positive, semi-definite (and symmetric?) kernels. Now its the finite L^2 norm of these kernels that make the induced integral operator bounded and hence Hilbert-Schmidt.

Comment: (3) Isn't Mercer's theorem all about giving better than L^2 convergence for the spectral decomposition of the HS operators?